# hacer submit via Javascript en un botón especifico en el Form

Tags: javascript

Con la Siguiente instruccion:

```
 document.forms["FormTab"].submit()
```

Ejecuto el Submit de un determinado formulario, si ese formulario tiene varios botones de tipo Submit, como puedo hacer submit de un botón en especifico. gracias.

Para dar mas detalle
.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este formulario lo tengo funcionando estoy trabajando con MVC como veran tengo los registros paginados,cuando le doy click al boton Nuevo me envia aun formulario en el cual ingreso un nuevo registro al grabar el registro y volver a esta ventana en la barra de direcciones se queda con el Controlador y la ultima acción ejecutada, los links de paginacion invocan el submit del formulario pero como este esta "apuntando" al controler y accion anterior vuelve a ejecutar la ultima accion y provoca un error, es por eso que quiero encontrar la manera de invocar el submit del boton Filtrar.

para ser mas exacto:

a ver, normalmente cuando entro y se lista los registros mi barra de direcciones queda así:

http://192.168.1.121/index.php?controlador=PagosController&accion=ListarChq

aca los presiono links de paginación y me muestra la pagina que clickeo pues cambio el valor de la pagina y lo envio aun PHP y este me devuelve los nuevos registros

Pero cuando hago otra accion (anular cheque) y regresa a mi listado la barra de direcciones queda asi:

http://192.168.1.121/index.php?controlador=PagosController&accion=AnularChq

entonces presiono link de Paginacion y se ejecuta el controller y accion que quedo en la barra de direcciones esto me produce un error. pero si presiono el botón filtrar se ejecutanormalmente todo. por ahora la solución que tengo es desde el controlador redireccionar al listado "limpiando" la barra de direcciones.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que quieres hacer, por que has de tener mas de un botón de tipo submit en tu formulario ? eso no se debería de hacer !

Comment: tienes varios botones submit, lo que quieres s saber con que boton se hizo submit?

Comment: agregue mas detalle de mi problema.

Comment: Entonces al hacer submit, y después cambiar de página, esta vuelve a hacer submit porque recargaste la página y marca error, es eso?

Comment: Aguegue algo mas a la explicación.

Comment: basicamente hace un submit de la ultima accion ejecutada, y se provoca el error.

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente es mejor trabajar con elementos `button`. Aunque puedes hacerlo con inputs o con cualquier otro elemento.

Los pasos serían muy simples.

1. Asignas un id único a cada `button`
2. En JS, usas `querySelectorAll` para seleccionar todos los elementos de tipo `button` del DOM.  Esto se podría refinar, seleccionado sólo los elementos de un determinado formulario por ejemplo.
3. `querySelectorAll` te devolverá un array con los botones. Lo recorres para asignar a cada uno la función `manejarBotones`, ligada al `click` de cada uno.
4. En la función `manejarBotones`  podrás usar `this.id` para saber qué botón fue presionado.

Espero te sirva.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

  var elBotones = document.querySelectorAll("button");
  console.log(elBotones);

  /*Asignamos  función para escuchar*/
  for (var i = 0; i < elBotones.length; i++) {
    elBotones[i].addEventListener("click", manejarBotones, false)
  }


});

/*Podremos usar  this.id  para identificar cada botón*/
function manejarBotones(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Has pulsado el botón: " + this.id);
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="GET-name">Nombre:</label>
  <input id="GET-name" type="text" name="name">
  <button id="btn1">Boton1</button>
  <button id="btn2">Boton2</button>
  <button id="btn3">Boton3</button>
</form>
```

**NOTA:** Ten en cuenta que no es obligatorio ir cambiando de página para realizar operaciones diversas, aunque estas tengan que realizarse en el servidor.

A través de peticiones Ajax tú puedes enviar/recibir o modificar datos en el servidor sin tener que cargar más páginas.

Desde el mismo JavaScript tú puedes modificar el DOM, presentando u ocultando elementos nuevos de forma dinámica, según las diferentes operaciones que vayas necesitando.

Answer (score 0):

Podría realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

Boton 1:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="javascript:return false;">Boton 1</button>
```

Boton 2: (Submit)

```
<button type="submit">Boton 2</button>
```

Boton 3:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="javascript:return false;">Boton 3</button>
```

saludos.

Comment: los botones ya los tengo programados todo funciona adecuadamente, agregue mas detalle a mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy trabajando por comodidad con varios botones del tipo Submit, cada uno con su formaction, el "problema" tan simple era que no tenia seteado el action del Formulario en si, ahora si funciona como deberia, de todas formas muchas Gracias A. Cedano. y Jeyson.

Answer (score 0):

añádele un id a los formularios por ejemplo `#formenvio_1`
y en el botón con el cual quieres ejecutar usa jquery

```
$("#formenvio_1").submit();
```

Comment: Deberías explicar por qué tu sugerencia soluciona el problema, tal y como está tu respuesta, aunque pudiera ser útil no es todo lo útil que podría ser.

Answer (score 0):

Archivo html o jsp el que estés usando

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>

    <!-- LLamada javascript que envía todos los campos que tengan declarado un name -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function send1() {
            //Acá se crea la variable del form y luego el método submit envía todo junto a donde esté declarado el action.
            var frm = document.frmInsertClient;
            frm.action = "InsertClientServlet"; // O página de acción.php
            frm.submit();
        }

        function send2() {
            //Acá se crea la variable del form y luego el método submit envía todo junto a donde esté declarado el action.
            var frm = document.frmInsertClient;
            frm.action = "deleteClientServlet"; // O página de acción.php
            frm.submit();
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <h1>Insertar Cliente</h1>

         <!-- Esto es un ejemplo nomás, si trabajas con php pones la de php en action -->
        <form action="" method="get" name="frmInsertClient">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Nombre: </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td><label>Apellido: </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastname" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Saldo: </label></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="savings" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" value="boton 1" onclick="send1()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="boton 2" onclick="send2()" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ya solucione mi problema, de todas maneras gracias por la ayuda.